# Exception in plugin Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, android-studio-2.0

Got this error after I updated my android studio to preview 5, when I click on deploy to app engine and select my cloud project it gives

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.execution.ui.layout.impl.RunnerContentUi.setLeftToolbar(RunnerContentUi.java:204)
    at com.intellij.execution.ui.layout.impl.RunnerLayoutUiImpl.setLeftToolbar(RunnerLayoutUiImpl.java:264)
    at com.google.gct.studio.deploy.AppEngineUpdater.startUploadingProcess(AppEngineUpdater.java:207)
    at com.google.gct.studio.deploy.AppEngineUpdater.access$100(AppEngineUpdater.java:67)
    at com.google.gct.studio.deploy.AppEngineUpdater$2$1.run(AppEngineUpdater.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:345)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:329)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Hi there,have you filed a bug for this?

http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: I did it now, thanks

Comment: @ManishPatiyal do you have the link for the bug? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218046&thanks=218046&ts=1469506956